# How do i return each value in a loop?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, return

Instead of printing each sentence, i want to return it!
But if i do return it will end the loop.

```
def printDeck(fileName):

    infile = open(fileName,'r') # open file
    contents = infile.readlines()   # read file
    infile.close()  # close file

    for sentence in contents:   # for each line in contents
        sentence = sentence.split() # eliminate spaces and turn into a list
        sentence[0], sentence[1] = sentence[1], sentence[0] # reverse order
        print('{0} of {1}'.format(sentence[0],sentence[1]))
```

This is the exercise im trying to solve:

Write a function called printDeck()which takes oneparameter, a file name. The function should read in the contents of the file and print it in the format shown below. For example: if 'Hearts 6' is read in from the file, the string should be printed as '6 of Hearts'. The function should return the contents of the file in list form.

Comment: You cannot return more than once. You can return a list or tuple if you want, but the control flow jumps back to the caller when you return.

Comment: Are you looking for `yield`?

Comment: Perhaps `printDeck` should be renamed to `getDeck`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only return a value in a function once. But you can append your generated strings to `mylst` and then return `mylst` after the loop is finished.

```
mylst = []
for sentence in contents:   # for each line in contents
    sentence = sentence.split() # eliminate spaces and turn into a list
    sentence[0], sentence[1] = sentence[1], sentence[0] # reverse order
    mylst.append('{0} of {1}'.format(sentence[0],sentence[1]))

return mylst
```

Comment: In general a generator is the superior solution to this problem. This answer reads the entire file into memory and then returns everything in one large list. You still need to iterate over that list to print, so you might as well take advantage of  a generator 's efficiency when solving this sort of problem.

Comment: At the time I wrote my answer we didn't even know a file was involved. But thank you for the clarifying comment.

Comment: It has always involved a file, but this answers the OPs question as it returns the required list object (which can also be done with a generator by calling `list()` on the generator object).

Comment: I didn't see it right away. Anyway, the OP accepted this answer and it is a viable solution (for small files at least).

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be a cards game so the amount of data should not be overwhelming. Let's just advise @Dan to consider iterators/generators if he experiences memory issues. In particular, `infile` already is one, so with files it really makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to create a generator:

```
def printDeck():
    """return contents of file as string"""
    ...
    for sentence in contents:   # for each line in contents
        ...
        yield '{0} of {1}'.format(sentence[0],sentence[1])
```

Then use it as

```
deck = printDeck()
deck1 = next(deck)
deck2 = next(deck)
etc.
```

or

```
for deck in printDeck():
    print(deck)
```

Comment: *Each time you call it it returns the next value.* That is not true. They need to call it once to get the generator object, and then iterate over that (or use `next()` on it).

Comment: True, I edited the answer. Sorry haven't done it in along time )

Comment: next(deck) is Python3

Comment: The question is tagged Python 3, and apart from that, it would still work in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a single sentence and stay in the loop.  You can return a list of the swapped phrases like this:

```
mylst = []
for sentence in contents:   # for each line in contents
    sentence = sentence.split() # eliminate spaces and turn into a list
    phrase = sentence[1] + " of " + sentence[0]
    mylst.append(phrase)

return mylst
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Write `printDeck()` as a generator that *yields* the strings. Then iterate over that generator to print.

You do not need to read the whole file into memory in one go with `readlines()`. If you open the file in a context manager (using `with`) then you do not need to worry about closing it - the context manager will ensure that that happens.

Reversal of the first 2 words of the sentence can be done with `str.format()` without bothering to actually swap the order after splitting.

You can write your code as a generator and more clearly like this:

```
def read_deck(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as f:    
        for sentence in f:
            yield '{0[1]} of {0[0]}'.format(sentence.split())

>>> for s in read_deck('deck.txt'):
...     print(s)
```

If you want all of the strings in one list, call `list()` on the generator:

```
>>> deck = list(read_deck('deck.txt'))
```